# How to set value for the form element using mootools

Tags: forms, select, input, mootools, element

I have a form that have input element and the select element with multi select. so how can I set value for the input element and select element in mootools.

Answer (score 8):

basically - `element.get("value");` returns the value for all inputs, selects and textareas, `.set("value", value);` to set them (except for multiples)

it's more complicated for select with multiple - the above returns the FIRST selected only, you need to do `element.getSelected().get("value")` to recieve an array of values (.getSelected() on its own will return the pointers to the actual `option` elements)

and finally, to set multiple selections, only way i can think of atm is to write your own element prototype that walks through child nodes with the values as specified and does `.set("selected", "selected")`

let me know if you need any help writing the latter

Answer (score 3):

For dropdown:

```
$('idOfSelect').selectedIndex = x;
```

For text:

```
 $('IdOfInput').value = 'Foo';
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this. like in jQuery('#idOfSelect').val([2,4]) or jQuery('#idOfInput').val('Foo')

Comment: about the select element I only know an array of value of the select element. how can I turn it into selectedIndex

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct about multiples, and needing to use `selectEl.getChildren('option').each(function(option)...`

but even for single selects, in IE (I'm testing this in IE9) if there is no "value" property in each option then Mootools fails, i.e. 
`selectEl.set('value', value)` does not work.  In FF it works and in IE it works if you set the "value" property of each  element.

My solution is:

```
selectEl.getElements('option').each(function(option) {
   option.selected = option.get('value')==value
});
```

Note that option.get('value') works even in IE, where there is no `value` property, Mootools supplies the option's `text`